# SpringBoot upgradation to 2.6.6 : Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at DefaultMetricsProvider.java:126

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-kafka

**Old Build File**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.2")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

String build_display_name = System.getenv("BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME")
String branch_name = System.getenv("BRANCH_NAME") ?: "local"
String workspace = System.getenv("WORKSPACE")
String cred_usr = System.getenv("CRED_USR")
String cred_psw = System.getenv("CRED_PSW")

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectKey', 'onc-devicemanager'
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'onc-devicemanager'
        property "sonar.branch.name", "${branch_name}"
        property 'sonar.projectVersion', "${build_display_name}"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/classes"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/test.exec"
    }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
        runtimeClasspath {
            extendsFrom developmentOnly
        }
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        credentials {
          username "${cred_usr}"
          password "${cred_psw}"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    springKafkaVersion = '2.5.3.RELEASE'
    commonsVersion='3.9'
    jUnitVersion='4.13.1'
    apachePoiVersion='4.1.2'
    commonsVersion='3.10'
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR5")
}

task printVersion {
    doLast {
        println project.version
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:$springKafkaVersion")
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.11.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:$apachePoiVersion")
    compile 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsVersion")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.0")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testCompile("junit:junit:$jUnitVersion")
    testCompile("commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:$springKafkaVersion")
    testCompile group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '3.1.6'
    /* shedlock */
    implementation group: 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock', name: 'shedlock-spring', version: '4.25.0'
    implementation group: 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock', name: 'shedlock-provider-mongo', version: '4.25.0'

    compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.5.1'
    compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.5.1'
    /* Logback Dependency */
    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')
    compile('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5')
    compile('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5')
    testCompile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')
    testCompile('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5')
    testCompile('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5')
    testImplementation 'guru.nidi:graphviz-java:0.18.1'
    testImplementation 'org.graalvm.js:js:20.0.0'
}


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

def sourcePath = "src/main/resources"
def destinationPath = "build/resources/test/"

task deploy(type: Copy) {
    from sourcePath
    into destinationPath
    include "fsm.yaml"
    rename("fsm.yaml", "for_validation_fsm.yaml")
}

compileJava.dependsOn(deploy)
```

**New Build File :**

```
 buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.6.6'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.2")
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
            classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2")
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
        id 'java'
        id 'jacoco'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
    
    String build_display_name = System.getenv("BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME")
    String branch_name = System.getenv("BRANCH_NAME") ?: "local"
    String workspace = System.getenv("WORKSPACE")
       
    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled true
        }
    }
    
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property 'sonar.projectKey', 'onc-devicemanager'
            property 'sonar.projectName', 'onc-devicemanager'
            property "sonar.branch.name", "${branch_name}"
            property 'sonar.projectVersion', "${build_display_name}"
            property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
            property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/classes"
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/test.exec"
        }
    }
    
    configurations {
        developmentOnly
            runtimeClasspath {
                extendsFrom developmentOnly
            }
            compileOnly {
                extendsFrom annotationProcessor
            }
        all {
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
            exclude group:'org.apache.logging.log4j', module:'log4j-slf4j-impl'
        }
    }
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        maven {
            credentials {
              username "${cred_usr}"
              password "${cred_psw}"
            }
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
    
    ext {
        springKafkaVersion = '2.8.1'
        commonsVersion='3.9'
        jUnitVersion='4.13.2'
        apachePoiVersion='4.1.2'
        commonsVersion='3.10'
        set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.2")
    }
    
    task printVersion {
        doLast {
            println project.version
        }
    }
    
    
    dependencies {
        implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:$springKafkaVersion")
        testImplementation ("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:$springKafkaVersion") {
    // needed if downgrading to Apache Kafka 2.8.1
            exclude group: 'org.apache.zookeeper', module: 'zookeeper'
        }
        testImplementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:$springKafkaVersion:test"
        testImplementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:$springKafkaVersion:test"
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
        implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")
        implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
        implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.13.2'
        implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-yaml', version: '2.13.2'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
        implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
        implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
        implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:$apachePoiVersion")
        implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
        implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsVersion")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.0")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.0")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.0")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.0")
        compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
        annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:$jUnitVersion")
        testImplementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0")
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    
        testImplementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test")
        testImplementation group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '3.1.6'
        /* shedlock */
        implementation group: 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock', name: 'shedlock-spring', version: '4.25.0'
        implementation group: 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock', name: 'shedlock-provider-mongo', version: '4.25.0'
    
        implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.5.1'
        implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.5.1'
        /* Logback Dependency */
        implementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')
        implementation('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5')
        implementation('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5')
        testImplementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')
        testImplementation('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5')
        testImplementation('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5')
        testImplementation 'guru.nidi:graphviz-java:0.18.1'
        testImplementation 'org.graalvm.js:js:20.0.0'
    }
    
    jar {
        enabled = false
    }
    
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }
    
    def sourcePath = "src/main/resources"
    def destinationPath = "build/resources/test/"
    
    task deploy(type: Copy) {
        from sourcePath
        into destinationPath
        include "fsm.yaml"
        rename("fsm.yaml", "for_validation_fsm.yaml")
    }
    
    compileJava.dependsOn(deploy)
```

**Junit File:**

```
public class TestKafkaConfig {
    @InjectMocks
    KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }
    @Test
    public void testKafkaInventoryConsumerFactory() {
        ProducerFactory<String, NotificationSchemaBean> inventoryProducerFactory = kafkaConfiguration.notificationProducerFactory();
        Assert.assertNotNull(inventoryProducerFactory);
    }
    @Test
    public void testConsumerFactory() {
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = kafkaConfiguration.consumerFactory();
        Assert.assertNotNull(consumerFactory);
    }
    @Test
    public void testKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = kafkaConfiguration.kafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        Assert.assertNotNull(factory);
    }
}
```

[Failing Junits:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y5MX.png)

```
ext {
    springKafkaVersion = '2.5.3.RELEASE'
    jUnitVersion='4.13.1'
    apachePoiVersion='4.1.2'
    commonsVersion='3.10'
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR5")
}
```

The above s/w versions upgraded as below ,

```
ext {
    springKafkaVersion = '2.8.6'
    jUnitVersion='4.13.2'
    apachePoiVersion='4.1.2'
    commonsVersion='3.10'
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.2")
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at DefaultMetricsProvider.java:126

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:581

When i upgrade the spring boot version from 2.3.1.RELEASE to 2.6.6, Above 3 Junits are failing. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Spring Kafka and Spring Cloud depend on certain versions of Boot. You should verify these do not conflict

Comment: Any official page where we can verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the below dependencies issue got solved,

```
compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.5.1'
compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.5.1'
```